# Drupal API - Attach Image to field_productimage

Tags: image, api, file, drupal

I have been trying to attach an image to products I create using drupal's API. So far I have been able to create products and add information to basic text fields (sku, title, price, etc...)

I have been having trouble adding to the field_productimage field that all products have. So far I can get drupal to upload the file to its public directory and register it in the file_managed table. How can I attach image files to the field_productimage data field?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `field_productimage` is a field of type `image`, here is how you can attach an image to the field.

```
$node = new stdClass();
// Build other node stuff here. 
// $file_id is the file ID from file_managed table. 
$file = file_load($file_id);
$node->field_productimage[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = (array) $file;
// again, other stuff. 
$node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving
node_save($node);
```

Make sure that `$file` object has `$file->fid` property and is numeric.